# How to open the folder/mailbox where is located a message I selected in a search result in the Mail App on macOS?

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-mail-app

In the Mail app of macOS, I work with lots of smart folders (a particular mailbox that shows the results of pre-defined search criteria).  Thus, these smart mailboxes show messages from different accounts and folders.

Usually, I need to jump to the actual mailbox/folder where is located a message selected in the list of results. I also have many folder.

One of the *improvements* (annoyances) in the new Mail app was that I could not find a way to do that. In past versions of macOS (at least up to Mavericks) this was easy. I could do the same as I still do in many other applications. See the image.

[image]

The previous trick is not working anymore in the message windows of the Mail App.

Is there any way to jump or open the mailbox/folder where is located a message I select in a search result or smart mailbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution with Automator + AppleScript

The solution I found was to create an Automator Service and optionally associate it with a shortcut.

1. Open Automator.
2. New Document.
3. Select `Service` for the type of document.
4. At the top of the window, set the input type for this service:
   `Service receives selected` choose `no input`
   `in` choose `Mail.app`
5. In the Actions library (left pane) find the action `Run AppleScript`.
6. Drag and drop it in the workflow area.
7. Copy the code at the end of this answer and paste it into the action `Run AppleScript`.
8. Save your service (e.g. "Jump to Folder").

### Test the service

When testing the service, Automator could remain open and also the Mail App.

1. Open Mail App.
2. Do a search and select one message, preferably a message located in a custom folder.
3. In the menu bar go to `Mail` > `Services`. You should see your new service.
4. Select the service.

The selected and active mailbox/folder should be the mailbox of the previously selected message.

### Optional. Assign a shortcut to your service:

1. Open System Preferences.
2. Go to `Keyboard` > `Shortcuts`
3. In the left pane select `Services`
4. At the end of the right pane under `General` you should find your service
5. Assign a shortcut to it (e.g. <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>OPTION</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>)

## The Code

```
set theDialogTitle to "Go to Folder Script"

tell application "Mail"

    -- Get the selected messages and the count of them
    set theMessageList to selected messages of message viewer 1
    set theCount to length of theMessageList

    -- Error if no messages
    if theCount is 0 then
        display dialog ¬
            "No message selected." with title theDialogTitle buttons {"OK"} with icon caution
        return
    end if

    -- Error if more than one message
    if theCount is greater than 1 then
        display dialog ¬
            "Must select only one message." with title theDialogTitle buttons {"OK"} with icon caution
        return
    end if

    -- Get the message
    set theMessage to item 1 of theMessageList

    -- Get the mailbox object
    set theMailbox to mailbox of theMessage

    -- Select the mailbox
    set selected mailboxes of message viewer 1 to theMailbox

end tell
```